# python: iterating over a large dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

First of all, am i right to assume that for:

```
dict1 = {'a':['b','c']}  
(key,value), = dict1.items()
```

assigns 'key' to be the keys of the dict and 'value' to be the values of the dict?
also, why is that comma after the (key,value), needed?

and to my real question:
how do i do this over a larger dictionary with 5+ values per key? when i try to do it on my dict, it says the following:

```
builtins.ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

is there a way to do this without the itertools module?

Comment: Instead of assuming you can always actually *run* the code. It's right there in front of you. I'm guessing it will grab the first key and value in the dict and assign them to `key` and `value` respectively. Unless the error you're getting is actually from that code, then it simply won't work if the `dict` has more than one item. The comma is needed because you're deconstructing a one-item *sequence* of `(key, value)` tuples - so you need to assign that to a one-item tuple of variables. (And each of those variables has to itself be a two-item tuple.)

Comment: If this is confusing, part of it stems that what you're doing is probably not the right way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do, which you haven't described too well. You should provide a code sample that actually causes the error you're having, and the results you're expecting.

Answer (score 3):

You are a bit vague, but there are two things I think you are asking for:

how to save all keys in a variable and all values in a variable:

```
values = dict1.values()
keys = dict1.keys()
```

or, and more likely so, you want to be able to use this to easily iterate through a dictionary:

```
for key,value in dict1.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the first assumption is incorrect. Given `dict1`:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': ['b', 'c']}
>>> dict1.items()
[('a', ['b', 'c'])]
```

So the result of `items` is a list. As you may know, Python has (to an extent) destructuring assignment:

```
>>> a, b = ['hello', 'world']
>>> a
'hello'
>>> b
'world'
```

It uses the syntax of tuples, and as you may know, to make a 1-tuple, you use a trailing comma:

```
>>> a, = ['hello']
>>> a
'hello'
```

Now what happens if you try to unpack something with the wrong number of values?

```
>>> a, = ['hello', 'world']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Oops! We get an error. So your problem was not having too many values per key; it was *having more than one key*.

If you want the keys and values separately, use the appropriate `dict` methods:

```
>>> dict2 = {'a': ['b', 'c'], 'd': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']}
>>> dict2.keys()
['a', 'd']
>>> dict2.values()
[['b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']]
```

Comment: Note that `dict2.keys()` and `dict2.values()` _is guaranteed_ to traverse the dict in the same order if you don't modify it inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a 'large dictionary' you need a loop construct:

```
>>> dict1={'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,8,9], etc}
>>> (key,value), = dict1.items() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> for k,v in dict1.items():
...    print k,v
... 
a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b [6, 7, 8, 9]
etc
```

The construct you have here:

```
(key,value),=dict1.items()
```

Is not doing what you think.

Python supports tuple assignment. The number on the Left Hand side needs to match the number on the Right Hand side:

```
x,y=1,2
```

(except for Python 3 which has the lovely `*` for LH assignments):

```
first, second, *the_rest=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

The trailing comma in `(key,value),` is ambiguous in this context in Py2 or Py3.

You use a trailing comma to construct a tuple with a single element:

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
>>> 1,2,
(1, 2)
```

With more than one element, it is ignored.

With the addition of parens on the LH then a trailing comma, you are creating a nested tuple:

```
>>> (1,2),
((1, 2),)
```

The only way you can assign to such a beast is to match the nesting on the RH:

```
>>> (x,y),z=((1,2),3)
>>> x,y,z
(1, 2, 3)
```

Without using parenthesis to create a tuple explicitly in Python, you need to be careful with the [order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages):

```
>>> (1,2)==1,2
(False, 2)
# probably not what is expected here...
```

You *can* do this:

```
>>> dict1={'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,8,9]}
>>> keys, values=dict1.keys(), dict1.values()
>>> keys
['a', 'b']
>>> values
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

And you can construct a dict from those two lists of keys/values using zip:

```
>>> dict(zip(keys,values))
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [6, 7, 8, 9]}
```